# Wifi on when phone is off?

Tags: wi-fi

See this pic

[image: screenshot]

Is this normal or a bug or something?

It states wifi is active though The device is turned off...

Android 5 moto g2.

Ive disabled "find my phone" via moto and google (at least I  think I have)

Thanks for ur time

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it just persisted the state that Wi-Fi was in when the device was shut off.  Given zero power consumption in that period, there's no reason to believe that the device was actually on and transmitting data over Wi-Fi.